# Custom Getter for Core Data attribute

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

I am introducing a soft-deletion pattern in my app. Instead of deleting objects from my context, I will be flagging them as 'deleted'. I'll use the example of (soft-)deleting ingredients from a recipe here.

I have many many places where I am requesting a recipe's ingredients. If possible, I would like to avoid updating all of these (and risk missing one). Instead, can I redefine the `ingredients` getter for the recipe class, where I will filter out the soft-deleted objects?

The few instances where I need the full list of ingredients (including soft-deleted) will use a new property, something like `ingredientsIncludingDeleted`.

Is this reasonable? Are there any notable side effects with using a custom getter that does something other than just returning what would be expected? Anything core data specific I should be aware of?

Comment: I'd rename the core data attribute; or use a differently named accessor for the undeleted ingredients. The accessor for the managed object property should just return the value of the property - KVC would be broken otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can do that. However, your approach is doing it backwards.
The default getter should not have any predicates. It should do exactly what it implies, which is an un-filtered result set. Think of someone reading your code 6 months later. Will they know that "ingredients" actually means "filteredIngredients" ? No.

So instead of changing the meaning of the **default** getter, create a new getter (named something like "filteredIngredients", and use that everywhere.  This is the correct long term solution.

If you're worried about forgetting to change the property in some places, do this: temporarily rename your ingredients getter to something else, like "tempIngredients". This will cause compiler errors everywhere it is used. Fix all those compiler errors by using the appropriate getter, and then rename your default getter back to "ingredients".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. It felt wrong, I must admit. Nice idea on the rename, too.

Comment: Instead of renaming the getter and creating compiler errors and stop your app from running, better add `__attribute__((deprecated))` to your getter definition. That will generate warnings, but will keep the app runnable.

Comment: I agree with @melsam but in my case I have created a new method in a Category which get the data from the default getter. Finally I return the data filtered.